# Image not displaying when loading HTML page through Node server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Heads up: I am very new to Node.js, so this code might not be the best way to do it all. I am still in the learning process.

When I run the .JS file through node and go to the localhost:1337, all of the HTML shows up correctly, but the image does not render. when i look in the source code, the image is being brought in as Text/HTML and not an image.

Why is this? Is that why the image is not being displayed?

This is my code so far.

```
var http    = require('http'),
fs      = require('fs'),
request = require('request'),
url     = require('url');


http.createServer(function (req, res)
  {
    console.log(req.url);
      var request  = url.parse(req.url, true),
          action   = request.pathname,
          html     = buildHtml(req);
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length': html.length,'Expires': new Date().toUTCString()});
      res.end(html);
  }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');



function buildHtml(req)
{
  var header = "",
      body   = '<img src="../Dilbert.jpg" alt="Dilbert">';
  return '<!DOCTYPE html>'
       + '<html><header>' + header + '</header><body>' + body + '</body></html>';
};

var download = function(uri, filename, callback)
{
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body)
    {
      console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
      console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
      request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
};

download('http://assets.amuniversal.com/145cd9c0fb4e0132ee37005056a9545d', 'Dilbert.jpg', function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Why are you passing an object as the `Content-Type`?  Don't you need to pick one?

Comment: @AaronDufour I am very new to Node.js. I was not aware there was another way to pass objects.

Comment: Are you expecting it to just server the image off the filesystem?  That's not going to happen, because your `createServer` function only responds with html.  You would have to write code to read the appropriate file off the file system and respond with it.

Comment: @AaronDufour Thank you. I figured it all out. I appreciate it.